# synapse pipeline copied data to azure synapse data lake table - serverless sql select shows rows, but spark sql select does not

Tags: azure-synapse

I made a new Azure synapse data lake database and table:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db1 LOCATION '/db1';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tbl1(id int, name string) USING CSV (header=true);
```

I then ran a synapse pipeline to copy data from a source to the ADLS sink for this table. I see the expected csv file in the ADLS container and folder - synapse-workspace-container/db1/tbl1/employee.csv:

```
id,name
1,adam
2,bob
3,charles
```

Running a serverless SQL select statement I see my rows:

```
SELECT TOP (100) [id]
,[name]
 FROM [db1].[dbo].[tbl1]
```

```
+---+-------+
| id|   name|
+---+-------+
|  1|   adam|
|  2|    bob|
|  3|charles|
+---+-------+
```

Running a pyspark sql select I see no rows:

```
sdf=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db1.tbl1 ORDER BY id ASC")
sdf.show()
```

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```

Why are no rows showing for spark sql?

Comment: BTW, I see that if I stop the session in the notebook, and run the spark sql select again (whereupon it starts a new spark session) it works. If I then change the data and re-run the pipeline, I now see the updated data when I re-run the spark sql select. Is this a bug? Or maybe there's some way to force a refresh in the current spark session the first time around. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest **`creating global temp view`**. As a result, you can use this **`view in any notebook`** you want as long as your cluster is not terminated. Having said that, you could create global temp view as below -

```
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("temp_view")
```

Kindly refer the below document:

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I will try it out and report back.